# C: add an element at the end of a list

Tags: c, list, compiler-errors, codeblocks

I would like to add an item at the end of the list. I don't understand why the program is compiling but then something goes wrong and stops the execution. Commenting on the last line of the function everything works, but clearly it loses the pointer to the last element of the list. I think it has something to do with the impossibility of "ptr" to modify its "pointer". Could someone help me? thanks

```
void add_element(struct element *ptr, int item) {

while(ptr != NULL) {
    ptr = ptr->pointer;
}
struct element *ptr2;
ptr2 = (struct element*)malloc(sizeof(struct element));
ptr2->number = item;
ptr2->pointer = NULL;
ptr->pointer = ptr2; }
```

Comment: After the `while(ptr != NULL)` loop, what is the value of `ptr`? Please [try to explain it to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: I have already seen its value. it is 0. So in the cycle if enters. thanks for the answer

Comment: Off-Topic: Using `sizeof *ptr2` is probably better because when you change the type of `ptr2` you will not forget to change `malloc()` this way. When you forget to change it for both you get UB. There is no need to cast the result of `malloc()` in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the last line of your code you wan't to assigne value to `ptr->pointer`, but in your while loop your condition said: if ptr is not NULL we continue, so after go out of your while loop `ptr` is equal to `NULL`.

To fix you probleme use this while loop:

```c
while(ptr->pointer != NULL) {
    ptr = ptr->pointer;
}
```

Comment: it works if i write ' while(ptr->pointer != NULL)' thanks a lot!

Comment: @Cb95 Also remember to add a check for `ptr == NULL` *before* the loop.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 I could not not avoid to see the irony in the combination of your comment and your user name :D